# Facing Issues while calling esignature API/SDK methods in Production Environment

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I have created one python application which is using Docusign integration.
First i developed it on Docusign Developer Account it works fine with its integration key.

Now i have done with "Go-Live" Process for production usage and that integration key i can see in my production account as well.

Also done with creating RSA Keypair ID, Redirect URI.

Also Provided the consent using the url

[https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={INTEGRATION_KEY}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/](https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BINTEGRATION_KEY%7D&redirect_uri=http://localhost/)

Also i have maintained my production account

user_id
account_id
client_id/integration_key
host

in .env file

And when i am running my application for accessing access token using esignature SDK method

```
`api_client = ApiClient()
   
      api_client.host = os.environ.get('HOST')
      api_client.oauth_host_name = os.environ.get('OAUTH_HOST_NAME')

      SCOPES = ["signature"]

      access_token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
            client_id=os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID'),
            user_id=os.environ.get('USER_ID'),
            oauth_host_name=os.environ.get('OAUTH_HOST_NAME'),
            private_key_bytes=private_key,
            expires_in=3688,
            scopes=SCOPES
        )`
```

it is throwing the Error:

```
(400)
Reason: Bad Request
Trace-Token: 587ff3c6-da1a-4907-9ac7-cff0cc069f62
Timestamp: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 05:33:53 GMT
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '587ff3c6-da1a-4907-9ac7-cff0cc069f62', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block; report=/client-errors/xss', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'AM2FE21', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer,strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Wed, 13 Dec 2023 05:33:53 GMT', 'Content-Length': '28', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'})

HTTP response body: b'{"error":"consent_required"}'
```

Even if I have given consent same Error Persists.
In Connected Apps section I can see the consent for my App

I Tried to resolve but did not find any solution.

Comment: Can you try to use 'impersonation' in your scope url for getting a consent? something like this: scope=signature%20impersonation.  Try this: https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id={INTEGRATION_KEY}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lbo is correct--you only obtained consent for scope `signature`. But you need consent for both `signature` and `impersonation`.

So try:

```
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&
scope=signature%20impersonation&
client_id={INTEGRATION_KEY}&redirect_uri=http://localhost/
```

Note that your SDK request for an access token via the JWT grant only needs to specify `signature` scope (as you are doing) since the impersonation scope is implied due to your use of the JWT (impersonation) OAuth flow